# BrowserSync doesn't show changes after browser reload

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

BrowserSync in the gulpfile below is not showing the changes made to index.html even after it says 'Reloading Browsers' in command line as well as the 'Connected to BrowserSync' notification in Chrome.

Another odd thing that's occurring is that after the third save of the index.jade file, the rendered website in Chrome completely disappears, nothing in the rendered DOM.

I've followed ShakyShane's recipe on github (with a few tweaks). It worked without the tweaks on another project I started, but I can't see what's wrong here.

My file structure is:

```
project-folder
  /app
    /css
    /jade
    /js
    /sass
    index.html
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/***********************************************************************************
1. DEPENDENCIES 
/***********************************************************************************/

var gulp = require ('gulp'),                        // gulp core
    plumber = require ('gulp-plumber'),             // disable interuption
    jade = require ('gulp-jade'),                   // jade compiler
    sass = require ('gulp-sass'),                   // sass compiler
    autoprefixer = require ('gulp-autoprefixer'),   // sets missinb browser prefixes
    browserSync = require ('browser-sync'),         // inject code to all devices
    reload = browserSync.reload;                    // browser sync reload

/*********************************************************************************
2. FILE DESTINATIONS (RELATIVE TO ASSETS FOLDER)
**********************************************************************************/

var target = {
    jadeSrc : 'app/jade/**/*.jade',                 // source of jade files
    htmlDest : 'app/',                              // html file destination
    sassSrc : 'app/sass/**/*.sass',                 // source of sass files
    cssDest : 'app/css',                            // minified css destination
    jsDest : 'dist/js'                              // where to put minified js
};

/**********************************************************************************
3. SASS TASK
***********************************************************************************/

gulp.task ('sass', function (){
    gulp.src(target.sassSrc)                        // get the files
    .pipe(plumber())                                // make sure gulp keeps runnin on errors
    .pipe(sass())                                   // compile all sass
    .pipe(autoprefixer())                           // complete css with correct vendor prefixes
    .pipe(gulp.dest(target.cssDest))                // file destination
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

/**********************************************************************************
4. JADE TASKS
**********************************************************************************/

gulp.task('jade', function(){
    var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

    gulp.src(target.jadeSrc)
    .pipe(jade({
        locals: YOUR_LOCALS,
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(target.htmlDest))
});
// separate watcher for browser-sync reaction to '.jade' file changes
gulp.task('jade-watch', ['jade'], reload);

/**********************************************************************************
5. BUILD SEQUENCES
**********************************************************************************/

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'jade'], function(){
browserSync({server: target.htmlDest});
gulp.watch(target.sassSrc, ['sass']);
gulp.watch(target.jadeSrc, ['jade-watch']);
});
```

Comment: Even i faced a similar problem when i was new to browser-sync usage,the commandline was saying "reloading browsers" but the browser was not refreshed at all, the problem was i had not included body tag in my html page where the browser-sync can inject script for its functionality,make sure your html page has body tag.